# query not working in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

"insert int register(name1,phone_no) values('" + sname.Text + "','" + phone_no.Text + "')"
The above query is not working in vb.net 2010.I'm using access database.A syntax error is showing in insert query statement.Can anybody help me...

Answer (score 0):

Is this query verbatim from your code? If so, you misspelled "into":

```
insert into register(name1,phone_no) values('" + sname.Text + "','" + phone_no.Text + "')
```

It's worth pointing out, though, that you should be validating your input text to avoid sql injection attacks.

Comment: This is VB, shouldn't you use & for string concatenation? Do you get the syntax error on compile, or is it a runtime error when you attempt the insert?